# Android MediaPlayer question

Tags: android, media-player, broadcastreceiver

I have the following code. I set up and alarm in HelloAndroid2.java, and after 2 seconds, AlarmReceiver.java shows me a Toast message. I wanted to add some audio to the app but I’m having some problems.

HelloAndroid2.java:

```
public class HelloAndroid2 extends Activity {  


@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);   

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
 intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

}
```

AlarmReceiver.java:

```
public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

Q1: If I put this code into HelloAndroid2.java:

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.onlyyou); 
`mp.start();`
```

It works fine.

How can I add an mp.stop() to the AlarmReceiver.java? It doesn’t know what mp is.

Q2: If i put the code in the AlarmReceiver.java file, there is a problem with getBaseContext() (says: undefined for the type AlarmReceiver)

Should I use some other context?

I hope it's okay that i raised to questions in one topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this the wrong way. You shouldn't be doing anything like what you're attempting in a broadcast receiver. If you want to start and stop audio, you'll need to do that in a service. In your broadcast receiver, you should send information to your service to know what to do with the media player.

Comment: Thank you!
In the AlarmReceiver.java i put the code:
 context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

And i created a MyService.java for the code which i found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html